# Unable to obtain the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine

Tags: batch-file, cmd, java-8

I have the following in a .bat file called RunTask.bat among other things:

```
call TaskExecution.bat %param1% %param2% debug
```

TaskExecution.bat contains this:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF DEFINED JAVA_HOME (
    %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -jar TaskExecution-1.0.jar %*
) ELSE (
    echo JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined, exiting...
)
```

TaskExecution-1.0.jar prompts for a password like so using java.io.Console:

```
Console console = System.console();
if (console != null) {
  char[] passwordChars = console.readPassword("Please enter the password: ");
  ...
} else {
  logErrorMsg("Unable to obtain the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine.");
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Question is, How can I within RunTask.bat invoke the call on the TaskExecution.bat but automatically pass a password without prompt?

For example, tried this:

```
echo password | call TaskExecution.bat %param1% %param2% debug
```

But get the following error:

```
2020-05-14T15:16:17,493 ERROR [TaskExecution] Unable to obtain the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine.
```

I understand that If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Have you tried to put the password as one of the arguments?

Comment: TaskExecution jar in my case cannot accept password by command argument - only by System Console readPassword()